# convert/parse YYYY-MM-DD object to string ot to JavaScript Date object

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

I have the following object 2019-12-01. When I do:

```
console.log(typeof 2019-12-01);
```

The output is: **NaN**

So I want to convert this to string like this "2019-12-01" or to date object like:

```
Sun Dec 01 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

I tried so many thing, but I cannot figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `typeof 2019-12-01` => `'number' - 12 - 01` => `'NaN' - 01` => `'NaN'`. Perhaps you meant `typeof '2019-12-01'`.

Comment: `new Date("2019-12-01")`

Answer (score 0):

Why `typeof`, you can just create a date object

```js
console.log(new Date("2019-12-01"))

console.log(new Date("2019-12-01").toISOString().replace(/T.*/, ""))
```